# careers.stackoverflow.com profile should have field for contact number

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Shouldn't the careers profile page also have a field for contact number? Its a very basic piece of information that needs to be on resume.

**EDIT:** If it has anything to do with the business model of career-2 then this information can only be visible in the print version of the page so at least if someone is applying for job by sending a hard copy or pdf in an email, it has all the details at least?

Answer (score 6):

That would be assuming that CV's are the same as resumes.

Putting contact information would take away from the Career's business model, as well as provide the people posting their CV's with a possibility of spam. By having all initial contact go through the site, you can monitor for spam-like activities, as well as make a profit so you can continue making great services.

Comment: @Hasan: Tyler said it. For now we have no plans to include any additional contact fields (and email address is only given to employer once you've indicated you're interested).

Answer (score 2):

We now provide this field for use in the PDF export feature.  **It will not show up on any public view of your profile.**  You can edit this field by clicking the button indicated in the image below:

[image]

And then follow that up by editing the following field:

[image]

The PDF generator can be reached through the sidebar on the edit page of your profile.

[image]

And on your resume, the phone number shows up at the top!

Comment: Extra +1 for picking on Punyon

Comment: I don't seem to have this field.  I simply have Location and then Website URL.  No phone.  Is there any reason for this?  I am in London.

Comment: @AaronChambers: There was a bug for some users, it will be fixed sometime before lunch (east coast).